# Excel VBA error 424 on Filtering Issue

Tags: vba, excel

Awesome StackOverflow users,
I have created a textbox to search a scope of information in Excel VBA. I use function filter to do the searching, but when I type something in the textbox, the error "424" appears. What should I do with that? Here is the code down below. Content is the name of a worksheet which includes a set of data that needs to be filtered.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
Content.AutoFilterMode = False
Else
If Content.AutoFilterMode = True Then
Content.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
Content.Range("T11:W" & Rows.count).AutoFilter field:=1, Criterial:="*" & TextBox1.Value & "*"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is Content? 424 means Object required.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code that is declaring and setting `Content`

Comment: In your implementation, Rows.count is the number of rows on the worksheet, not within Content.

Comment: In your implementation, Rows.count is the number of rows on the worksheet, not within Content.

Comment: Content is the name of a worksheet which includes a set of data that needs to be filtered.